# Java coding COSC Lab

Tags: java, matrix

So I wrote this code below. and I cant figure out what is wrong with it. I'm trying to print out the operations and I did something. now it won't print.
this was the prompt.

Write a method to add two matrices and a method to multiply two matrices. The headers of the two methods are:

```
public static double [] [] multiplyMatrix(double[][] a, double[][] b)
public static double [] [] addMatrix(double[][] a, double[][] b)
```

Write a test program that prompts the user to enter three 3*3 matrices and displays output.

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuVf6.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment8{

private static Scanner sc;
public static double[][] multiplyMatrix(double[][] c,double[][] d){
      double x[][]=new double[3][3];
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
          for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
               for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
                    x[i][j]=c[i][k]*d[k][j];
      return x;}

public static double[][] addMatrix(double[][] a,double[][] b){
      double d[][]=new double[3][3];
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
          for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
                d[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
      return d;}

 public static void main(String args[]){
      sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      double a[][]=new double[3][3];
      double b[][]=new double[3][3];
      double c[][]=new double[3][3];
      double d[][]=new double[3][3];
      double sum[][]=new double[3][3];
      double mul[][]=new double[3][3];


      System.out.println("Enter the elements of matrix a:");
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
          for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
               a[i][j]=sc.nextInt();


      System.out.println("Enter the elements of matrix b:");
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
          for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
               b[i][j]=sc.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter the elements of matrix c:");
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
          for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
               c[i][j]=sc.nextInt();


      sum=addMatrix(a,b);


      mul=multiplyMatrix(c,d);
 }


      public static void printResult(                                                        
              double[][] a, double[][] b, double[][] c, double[][] x, char op1, char op2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++)
                System.out.print(" " + a[i][j]);

              if (i == a.length / 2)
                System.out.print( "  " + op1 + "  " );
              else
                System.out.print( "     " );

              for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++)
                System.out.print(" " + b[i][j]);

              if (i == a.length / 2)
                System.out.print( "  " + op2 + "  " );
              else
                System.out.print( "     " );

              for (int j = 0; j < c[0].length; j++)
                System.out.print(" " + c[i][j]);

              if (i == a.length / 2)
                System.out.print( "  =  " );
              else
                System.out.print( "     " );

              for (int j = 0; j < x [0].length; j++)
                System.out.print(" " + x [i][j]);

              System.out.println();
            }
          }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use the `nextInt()` method of `Scanner` while reading in the third matrix, but in the sample run in the image, you entered a decimal value instead of an integer.

If you want to be able to enter decimal values, try `nextFloat()` or `nextDouble()` instead.

...also, you should call the `printResult` method at some point in `main()` if you want the output to appear.

Comment: it did not change anything so i guess that's not the issue. it was a flub on my part sending that. but its something else. even if you entered that code without decimals in the input it still wont output the data

Comment: @AndrewBourg and adding a call to `printResult` changes nothing?

Comment: I apologize I read it so fast that I only saw the first part lol. but how would I do that. I'm still not too familiar with the vocabulary. so i'm not entirely sure what youre telling me to put in the main method

Comment: @AndrewBourg `printResult(a, b, c, mul, "*", "+");`?

Comment: thank you so much man. I had to do some extra changes like changing some variables in the print sequence to string to make it all work. But you helped me complete it. it makes sense that it needed to call the varibles from the printing sequence to make it work. Once again thank you man you helped a lot.